# how do i reverse the letters in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, function, return, reverse

i want to reverse the order of characters in a string 
so take strings as arguments
and return s new string with letters of the original string 
example - "hello" would return "olleh"

All I have gotten to is:

```
def reverse(" "):
   string = input("Give me a word")
   x = ord(string)
   print(x)
```

Comment: There's a function called `reversed`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
"hello"[::-1]
```

You can read about extended-slices [here](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices)

Comment: Correct. The "martian smiley" is the best way to reverse a string.